# help in events of checkbox_checkedchange and button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, buttonclick

basically i have a few check boxes. if checkbox 1 is checked, i will assign a string to a variable. so i will have each check boxes having their own strings which will be saved into a text file.

only when a button is clicked, then these strings will be saved into text file.

i did this:

```
    protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string masterbuild1 = "Exec_Build_starting_mail";
}

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // create a writer and open the file
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("C:/Documents and 
Settings/Cha57061/Desktop/New Folder/C#/new/build.txt");

            // should i have a if statement like:
if CheckBox1_CheckedChanged = true
            {
            tw.Write(masterbuild1);
            }
            // close the stream
            tw.Close();
```

i think i need to add upon button click an if else statement.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check the state of the `checkbox` in button click and assign the string values.
If you cannot do that then in the `Check_Changed` event assign it to viewstate and then in the button click check for the value and proceed further.
(The event fires for checking and unchecking.. not sure what are you looking for !)

Comment: thanks. i figured out. on buttonclick event i did a if (checkbox1.checked) {do something}; it works well